# Unresolved compilation problem caused by personAA

Tags: java

I'm not sure why I'm getting unresolved compilation error for personAA object.

```
public static Person getOldest(Person personA, Person personB, Person personC) {
    Person Person_list[] = new Person[3];// declaration and instantiation
    Person_list[0] = personA;
    Person_list[1] = personB;
    Person_list[2] = personC;

    if (personA == null && personB == null && personC == null) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        return null;
    } else if (personA == null || personB == null || personC == null) {
        int max = 0;
        Person personOI1 = personA;
        for (int i = 0; i < Person_list.length; i++) {
            if (Person_list[i] != null) {
                if (Person_list[i].getAge() > max) {
                    max = Person_list[i].getAge();
                    personOI1 = Person_list[i];

                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Max age is");
        System.out.println(max);
        System.out.println(personOI1.getName());
        Person personAA = personOI1;

    }
    return personAA;
}
```

Comment: What value do you expect `personAA` to have if `personA == null || personB == null || personC == null` is false?

Comment: It would have something like this Person personC = new Person(18, "Ben", "F")

Answer (score 1):

PersonAA is defined with in brackets. You then reference it outside the the brackets.

```
public static Person getOldest(Person personA, Person personB, Person personC) {
    Person Person_list[] = new Person[3];// declaration and instantiation
    Person personAA=null; // *** Try to define personAA here
    Person_list[0] = personA;
    Person_list[1] = personB;
    Person_list[2] = personC;

    if (personA == null && personB == null && personC == null) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        return null;
    } else if (personA == null || personB == null || personC == null) {
        int max = 0;
        Person personOI1 = personA;
        for (int i = 0; i < Person_list.length; i++) {
            if (Person_list[i] != null) {
                if (Person_list[i].getAge() > max) {
                    max = Person_list[i].getAge();
                    personOI1 = Person_list[i];

                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Max age is");
        System.out.println(max);
        System.out.println(personOI1.getName());
        personAA = personOI1;

    }
    return personAA;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`personAA` is unaccessible outside the `else if` block therefore you cannot return this at the very end of method body

You should move `return` inside `else if` block

```
} else if (personA == null || personB == null || personC == null) {
    // ...
    System.out.println(personOI1.getName());
    Person personAA = personOI1;
    return personAA; // or even better just return personOI1
}
```

And define some default value that will be returned in case of `if` and `else if` are not satisfied (maybe `null`?) - then add returning of it in a current place of `return personAA`

Another option is to create variable **before** `else if` block and just change it's value inside

```
    Person personAA = null;

    if (personA == null && personB == null && personC == null) {
        // ...
    } else if (personA == null || personB == null || personC == null) {
        // ...
        personAA = personOI1;
    }
    return personAA;
}
```

---

Read more:

- [Java variables scopes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/)

Comment: i made the following change to fix the scope, and it did cause a new problem. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: This method must return a result of type Person

Comment: this is because anyway you need to return something at the very end - I edited answer while ago

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because personAA is declared inside else condition. And you are returning it outside the else block. As the solution

Either declare Person personAA outside else block

```
Person personAA = null;

if (personA == null && personB == null && personC == null) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
} else if (personA == null || personB == null || personC == null) {
    // your code
    personAA = personOI1;
}

return personAA;
```

Or return directly from else block

```
if (personA == null && personB == null && personC == null) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    return null;
} else if (personA == null || personB == null || personC == null) {
    // your code
    return personOI1;
}
```

Comment: else if (personA == null || personB == null || personC == null) {
   int max=0;
   for (int i = 0; i < Person_list.length; i++) {
    if (Person_list[i] != null) {
     if (Person_list[i].getAge()>max) {
      max=Person_list[i].getAge();
      personOI1=Person_list[i];
      
     }
    }
   }
   Person personAA=personOI1;
  }
  return personOT1;
  }

Comment: i did add the declaration to the beginning of method and still get the  personOT1 cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: You need to return personAA not personOT1 . As we have declared personAA outside the else block. These are 2 different solution.